# How do I paste to console Vim from the system clipboard?

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard, paste

I can copy text from Vim to other Mac applications with `"*y`. But when I try to paste into Vim, from TextEdit for example, I cannot paste text with `"*p`. Is there some setting that I missed?

Comment: What version (including patch level) do you run?

Comment: what does console mean on Mac? tty? or terminal?

Comment: @romainl, I'm using 7.3 with patch 1-286, and it has `+clipboard`

Comment: @Kent, I'm on the terminal with iTerm2

Comment: @Kit, You should install MacVim. You can run it in the terminal with `$ mvim -v`.

Comment: @romainl, Okay thanks.  Not trying to force it, but any idea why `"*p` doesn't work with terminal Vim?

Answer (score 6):

`"*p` *and* `"*y` don't work in the default Vim shipped with OS X simply because it was not compiled with clipboard support.

You may be led to believe that they work, somehow, because Vim won't complain if you use a non-existing register and yank in or put from the default register instead. `:reg +` and `:reg *` should show no content at all.

It's easy to verify if your Vim comes with clipboard support. The following command

```
$ /path/to/vim --version | grep clipboard
```

should find `-clipboard` and `-xterm-clipboard` which mean "no clipboard support".

The only *practical* way to have clipboard support is to install a proper Vim build, either by downloading MacVim, by using a package manager like Homebrew or Macports or by compiling it manually. I'd suggest the first option: it's the least geeky but the simplest and fastest.

Comment: note that in my vim, both clipboard and xterm-clipboard are enabled and yet * and + do not work.

Comment: @IttayD, which is not normal if you run Vim locally. Ask a question with the full output of `$ vim --version` and all the details you can give about your environment.

Answer (score 2):

No need to install MacVim, just put this line in your .vimrc file:

set clipboard=unnamed

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** It seems the default version that ships with Mac OS (Mountain Lion) doesn't come compiled with clipboard support. Since this is the case I would recommend just using `Command+V` to paste from the system clipboard or installing a new version of vim through [macports](http://www.macports.org).

Use `"+p` instead.

I believe `+` is register that refers to the system clipboard.

Comment: On Mac OS X, `"+` and `"*` are equivalent.